# Admin folder not working after adding php router (AltoRouter)

Tags: php, .htaccess, router, altorouter

I am working on a php project. I am using AltoRouter for this one. In order for AltoRouter to work I need to add this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

to the .htaccess file. What this does is, correct me if wrong, make sure that all request (hyperlink) is first carried to the index.php. No problem till now and everything works great.

I have an admin folder and to login I have to go to

```
http://www.example.com/admin/
```

but it shows nothing. I believe the newly added AltoRouter is the cause for this problem. Can any other AltoRouter / php-router user out there help me figure this out.

P.S. Not sure but do I need to Map the Admin Folder as well?

Comment: please check your Apache server 000-default file. because .htaccess does not work.

Comment: .htaccess does not work for what purpose and what is that you need me to check into the apache server?

Comment: Try adding this line as well to your .htaccess: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, same result ... nothing shows up.

Comment: Then try to put a `.htaccess` with `RewriteEngine Off` in the admin folder.

Comment: I get what you say @MagnusEriksson, but you need to type in the address http://www.example.com/admin into the address bar of the browser and as soon as you hit enter I guess the htaccess at the root folder with the above codes forward your request to the index.php at the root.

Comment: Look at this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924987/how-to-stop-sub-directory-inheriting-parents-htaccess-rules - It gives you another alternative, that should work.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, thanks mate, it worked .... but If I need to use the router in the admin too then do I need to map it too?

Comment: If you DO need the router there, then don't have a folder called `/admin/`, but rather let the router take care of it all. Better to just have one way, instead of mixing ways of doing it.