# How to access subdirectories:

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, subdirectory

For some reason on my website, I can only access sites in the root folder like this:

```
http://domain-name.com/[file]
```

BUT I can't access sub directories. For example, the following does not work:

```
http://domain-name.com/[folder1]/[file]
```

I am using `Hostinger` as my webhost. I have a feeling my `.htaccess` is configuered incorrectly. Here is the `.htaccess` currently:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://domain-name.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://domain-name.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Check this out and see if it answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924987/how-to-stop-sub-directory-inheriting-parents-htaccess-rules

Comment: Remove the slash from your last rule's pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write a rule for needed file extensions ( below example for `apache` and `nginx` ):

```html
# apache configuration
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|css|eot|svg|swf|ttf|woff|woff2|map|pdf|doc|docx|rar|zip)$ index.php

# nginx configuration
location / {
rewrite !\.(js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|css|eot|svg|swf|ttf|woff|woff2|map|pdf|doc|docx|rar|zip)$ /index.php;
}
```

[Read more.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html)