# Installing a second WordPress instance in a subfolder issue

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a shared Linux hosting on which I want to host 2 website.
In `/public_html/` I have hosted `example.com` and on `/public_html/example2/` I have hosted `example2.com`

**`.htaccess` of example.com**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

#Custom Error Pages
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.example.com/error-403/
```

**`.htaccess` of example2.com**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

#Custom Error Pages
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.example2.com/error-403/
```

I want to access both the website separately with www version i.e.

- example.com as https://www.example.com/ (*has SSL it's in main directory*)
- example2.com as http://www.example2.com/ (*do not have SSL and it in sub directory*)

*Please Note: I have setup `site_url` and `home_url` and above given URL in WordPress General settings.*

**Problem that I'm facing is**

When I access `example2.com` it is taking me to `https://www.example.com/example2/`

So after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924987/how-to-stop-sub-directory-inheriting-parents-htaccess-rules), and I changed my `.htaccess` of `example.com` to

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# if request is not for the /example2/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example2/ [NC]

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

So now `example2.com` is accessible but permalink is not working so when I try to reset it, it is deleting the content of my example2 `.haccess` file and redirecting me to `https://www.example.com/example2/`.

Can any one help me out here?

I also tried this with no luck [Configuring WordPress .htaccess to view subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196500/configuring-wordpress-htaccess-to-view-subfolders).

Answer (score 0):

I think that htaccess for example 2 should be like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /example2
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
 # END WordPress

 #Custom Error Pages
 ErrorDocument 403 http://www.example2.com/error-403/
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it seems to be not working, coz now it is redirecting to `https://www.example.com/example2/`.